# Copy a duplicity backup to another destination

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I have a Duplicity backing up to an S3 bucket. It has `n` backups, acquired over a few years. I've recently bought an external drive to have a more local version immediately available. Is there a Duplicity command to seed the new drive by copying the last full backup (possibly also any incremental backups since then) from the S3 bucket to the new drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You can, however, manually copy the needed files using a S3 frontend of your choice. The backup files you need from the backend are named pretty straight forwardly, containing the date and 'FULL' in the file name.

Simply copy all files from the last full backups onwards to a local folder and then point duplicity to it. You should run a verify on that location to make sure you've got them all.

Note: if you want to subsequently backup to both local and remote at the same time, try [the multi backend as documented in the duplicity man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect18).

Comment: Was there a URL supposed to be posted in the last line? Maybe it was cut off?

Comment: That's the answer's author's sign-off. (Which I only realised after editing the post to add a link and having seen more of their answers.)